# Split String after every x Digits

Tags: java, string, split, numbers, addition

I have a little problem. I need to split a String into x parts and add it together. EDIT: if i want to split it with x=3 then i will need 4 parts but if i want to split it with x=4 then i will need 3 parts. So my hardcoded code is bad.
and my x always a multiple of my stringlength ( 3 is a multiple of 009056737152 - length 12)

Example: String : "009056737152" and adresslength = 3; means i have to split the string after 3 numbers. 009 056 737 152 and then i have to add this together from right to left : 251 + 737 + 650 + **009** = 1647.My code is actually not working porperly. Any other Ideas ?

```
    int adresslength = 3;
    String str = "009056737152"; System.out.println(str);
    String result = str.substring(0,str.length() - adresslength - adresslength - adresslength );
    String result2 = str.substring(adresslength,str.length() + -adresslength -adresslength );
    String result3 = str.substring(adresslength + adresslength,str.length() +  -adresslength  );
    String result4 = str.substring(adresslength + adresslength + adresslength,str.length()  );
    System.out.println(result); System.out.println(result2);System.out.println(result3);System.out.println(result4);
```

Comment: which part is not working? the splitting?

Comment: is the length of the string always a multiple of the address length?

Comment: yeah always the multiple and it is not working when i change the int adresslength. its only working for int adresslength = 3

Comment: `String result3 = str.substring(adresslength + adresslength,str.length()   +adresslength -6);` if its not working when you change the length its because here you hard coded `6` which will only work if the address length is `3`

Comment: thanks i corrected it but still it does only work for 3 or 2

Comment: why do you add 009 instead of 900?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, this code resolve your problem...

```
    int adresslength = 3;
    String str = "009056737152";
    System.out.println(str);
    String[] result = new String[str.length() / adresslength];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length();) {
        result[j] = str.substring(i, (i + adresslength));
        char[] aux = new char[adresslength];
        int k2 = 0;
        for (int k = aux.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
            if ((j == 0)) {
                aux[k2] = result[j].charAt(k2);
                k2++;
            }else{
                aux[k2] = result[j].charAt(k);
                k2++;
            }

        }
        result[j] = String.copyValueOf(aux);
        i = i + adresslength;
        System.out.println(result[j]);
        j++;
    }

    int aux = 0;
    for (String string : result) {
        aux += Integer.valueOf(string);
    }
    System.out.println(aux);
```

Comment: THANKS:D this is great

Comment: you have a idea how to cut the result if the digits are more than my adresslength. example: adresslength= 3
but result is 1647 (length 4). How can i cut the first digit to get only 647

Comment: Humm... add these lines in final String `sumString = String.valueOf(aux); while(sumString.length() > adresslength){ sumString = sumString.substring(1, sumString.length()); }`

Answer (score 0):

If you first calculate the size of a part, you can easily calculate the part ranges.

```
public static String[] partitionByCount(String input, int count) {
    if (count <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid count: " + count);
    int size = input.length() / count;
    if (size * count != input.length())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("String of length " + input.length() +
                " cannot be split into " + count + " equally-sized parts");
    String[] parts = new String[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        parts[i] = input.substring(i * size, (i + 1) * size);
    return parts;
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(partitionByCount("009056737152", 2)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(partitionByCount("009056737152", 3)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(partitionByCount("009056737152", 4)));
```

*Output*

```
[009056, 737152]
[0090, 5673, 7152]
[009, 056, 737, 152]
```

If you want to specify the partition size instead of the partition count, the code is easily adjusted:

```
public static String[] partitionBySize(String input, int size) {
    if (size <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid size: " + size);
    int count = input.length() / size;
    if (count * size != input.length())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("String of length " + input.length() +
                " cannot be split into equally-sized parts of length " + size);
    String[] parts = new String[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        parts[i] = input.substring(i * size, (i + 1) * size);
    return parts;
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(partitionBySize("009056737152", 2)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(partitionBySize("009056737152", 3)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(partitionBySize("009056737152", 4)));
```

*Output*

```
[00, 90, 56, 73, 71, 52]
[009, 056, 737, 152]
[0090, 5673, 7152]
```

To then sum the parts reversed, it would be easier to reverse the input, partition it, then sum:

```
public static int sumReversedPartitions(String input, int size) {
    String reversed = new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString();
    String[] parts = partitionBySize(reversed, size);
    return Arrays.stream(parts).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum();
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(sumReversedPartitions("009056737152", 2));
System.out.println(sumReversedPartitions("009056737152", 3));
System.out.println(sumReversedPartitions("009056737152", 4));
```

*Output*

```
153         // 25 + 17 + 37 + 65 + 09 + 00
2538        // 251 + 737 + 650 + 900
7182        // 2517 + 3765 + 0900
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] main){
         int adresslength = 3;
         String str = "009056737152"; System.out.println(str);
         int result = 0;
         for(int i=0;i<str.length();i+=adresslength){
             String subString = str.substring(i , i+adresslength);
             String nSString = new String();
             for(int j=subString.length()-1;j>=0;j--){
                 nSString += subString.charAt(j);
             }
             result+=Integer.valueOf(nSString);
         }
         System.out.println(result);
    }
```

You can change adresslength for 2,4,5 and additionally add constrains as your requirement such as adresslength would be module by string length and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorter version using Java 8 streams.

```
public static int splitNumber(String s, int length) {
    s = new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString();
    return IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + length)
            .mapToObj(start -> s.substring(start, start + length))   // Take the i-th substring
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)                             // Turn into int
            .limit(s.length() / length)                              // Limit the number of parts
            .sum();
}
```